# distinguish between float and double in java---code in java

Tags: java

For eg: 5.00 is a double value. it should be truncated to assign to float or write 5.00f.so how can we write a code so that float and double gets differentiate and short , int , long too.

Comment: Long has suffix L like 1L. other constants are int by default if in not possible to define type from context.

Comment: Do you want to ***identity*** if a number is flot/double/int exc ? Or ***convert*** it ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for is the term called *downcasting*. Checkout *type-casting* which applies to many of the languages including java.